# JSON. Пределы возможного

Tags: json, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток, ув. сообщество. Перейду сразу к делу:

- Какой максимальный объём JSON данных можно забрать с сервера? **Неограниченно**
- Какой максимальный объём JSON данных можно забрать с сервера без вреда для него и клента? **Ограниченно железом**
- Какой максимальный объём JSON данных можно хранить на клиенте?
- Какой максимальный объём JSON данных можно хранить на клиенте без вреда для системы? **2 Гб ± ...**
- Как можно оптимизировать загрузку большого объёма данных(кроме Lazy loading)? **Параллельная загрузка**
- Как можно оптимизировать хранение большого объёма данных на клиенте(кэширование, может Local Storage)?

Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихься.

**UPD:** [JSON Compression algorithms](http://web-resource-optimization.blogspot.com/2011/06/json-compression-algorithms.html) - что можете сказать об этом? **Чепуха © [[@karmadro4](/users/6679/karmadro4)](/users/6679/karmadro4)**

---

[[@rnd_d](/users/672/rnd_d)](/users/672/rnd_d), данные я собираюсь рендерить, не все сразу конечно, но чтобы не тратить время ещё и на загрузку этих данных, они мне нужны ввиде Backbone.Collection на клиенте

[[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope), на сколько мне известно, кол-во параллельных запросов на один домен ограничено, в Opere например, по умолчанию стоит 16, но можно увеличить до 128, как обстоят дела в других браузерах не знаю.

Comment: Как раз сегодня появилась [статья на Хабре][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/140677/

Comment: спасибо, сейчас почитаем

Comment: @Spectre - да, ограничено, но так вы будете использовать эту возможность по максимуму.

Да и не стоит забывать что таким образом вы можете хоть как-то отвечать пользователю походу, а не тупо тянуть и ждать хз сколько пока прийдет все целяком. Ну вы меня поняли. К тому-же, если обрабатывать все по частям нам не прийдется в 1 прекрасный момент парсить целую кучу JSON'a (что будет во время парсинга, писать, думаю, не стоит =))

PS: к тому-же, никто не мешает сделать под-домены

Comment: в ASP.NET MVC существуют AsyncResult`ы, поэтому проблем с ожидаем думаю не будет. А вы случайно не искали js библиотек реализующий подобный функционал, я не ставлю под сомнение ваш код, просто  подобные библиотеки, чаще всего, задокументированы и поддерживаются.

Comment: Нет не искал, просто знаю их огромное множество, работают они все без исключения примерно так-же. Как вариант [вот](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Из того что знаю, как по мне - самое простое и интуитивно понятное.

Если интересует больший список - задайте вопрос я отвечу развернуто

Comment: Спасибо, думаю, мне будет достаточно и этого=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знаю что кто-то писал java софтину, где обрабатывали **> 2гб json'a**( что привело к необходимости фикса JSON парсера 4 java ). Так что юзать можно по полной.

С учетом того, что в большинстве браузеров парсинг JSON реализован на нативном уровне - скорость тоже на уровне.

Вообще если вы пишите приложение, где удобно было бы использовать json формат данных - стоит посмотреть в сторону noSQL документно-ориентированных бд (mongoDB, couchDB).

По поводу хранения большего количества данных - Local storage + запрос вида - не поменялись ли данные(если поменялись, естественно, тянем новые), при желании можно придумать что-то посложнее и поинтереснее, но не думаю что в этом есть смысл, а если и будет - то это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: даааа, преобразование реляционных данных в объекты, а потом эти объекты в JSON тоже затратно, но использовать noSQL пока не охота, может в будущем...=)

Comment: ооооочень зря, я после такого опыта вообще не желаю работать с sql базами данных, даже подташнивает xD

Comment: я тоже одно время брался, [пруф](http://hashcode.ru/questions/51309/sterling-nosql-oodb), но пока нету времени переделывать все наработки, да и LINQ to SQL я люблю

Answer (score 3):

> Какой максимальный объём JSON данных
> можно забрать с сервера?

Поскольку json это для начала всего лишь строка, а размер строки в js не ограничен то гипотетически можно передать сколько угодно. Проблема будет именно в парсинге этой строки на стороне клиента, время парсинга зависит от: аппаратной конфигурации, браузера(его рализации js), метода парсинга. То есть на мощной машине можно без проблема забрать 20 mb json'a и превратить их в js объект. На мобильнике эта же операция может запросто повесить браузер.

Мне кажется вы прекрасно это понимаете и без меня, но не очень понятно почему у вас такой абстрактный вопрос о максимальном количестве данных на сферическом клиенте в вакууме.

Кстати вот [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140677/) есть про максимальный размер кэша.

Comment: просто есть необходимость в большой скорости работы с самим web-приложением, т.е. как вы понимаете, чем чаще я буду забирать данные с сервера, тем больше будет издержек на клиенте, так вот мне интересно, сколько данных я смогу забрать сразу при старте приложения, чтобы работать с объектами уже в памяти, а самое главное как это кол-во максимально увеличить, чтобы не критично пострадала производительность

Comment: Для большой скорости нужно разбивать все на отдельные JSON "файлы". И тянуть асинхронно, порциями. По ходу того как данные приходят - делать соответствующие дейтсвия.

Comment: т.е. если я правильно вас понял, загрузить сначала необходимое пользователю в данный момент времени, а потом в фоне по мере работы загружать остальное до определённого предела?

Comment: Нет, например нам сейчас нужно 20мб JSON'a. Нужно разбить все запросы на несколько (чем больше тем лучше). По мере поступления тех или иных данных - мы можем делать что-то по частям.

Естественно все это дело должно быть асинхронным, но тут думаю и так понятно.

PS: в некоторых случаях полезно имитировать паралельность. Если например по приходу частей мы ничего не можем сделать и нам нужно сразу все.

Comment: я примерно тоже самое имел ввиду и наверно на этом сконцентрируюсь

Comment: Если интересно - я писал о чем-то подобном здесь. [Тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/87809/xmlhttprequest-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=87817#87817) тупой полет мыслей, но не думаю что для вас это будет проблема

Comment: Мой компетенции в js просто недостаточно, чтобы осознать всей сути вашего ответа=)

Comment: @AlexWindHope , я правильно понимаю, вы предлагаете просто разбить все большие запросы данных на максимально количество независимых запросов, что бы не ждать пока загрузиться и распрасится большой запрос? Ну и по возможности, если части данных не зависят от остальных использовать их по прибытию? 

Если не секрет @Spectre, что вы собираетесь делать с большим количеством данных на клиенте?

Comment: Примерно так, важно понимать что "паралельность" запросов это очень существенный выйграш по времени, не зависимо от того, какой интернет у клиента

Answer (score 2):

> UPD: JSON Compression algorithms - что можете сказать об этом?

Чепуха. Это не алгоритмы и даже не сжатие, а просто представления с уменьшением избыточности. С вполне очевидными последствиями.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать с чем работать не стоит